# Trying to display a phone number as it is entered with buttons using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a project in which I am trying to have an empty label populate with the numbers that are being clicked. However, I am having trouble with my code behind my web form and cannot get it to work. My code behind:

```
public partial class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ArrayList phoneNumber = new ArrayList() { };
        int counter = 0;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnNum1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            phoneNumber[counter - 1] = 1;
            lblNumbers.Text = phoneNumber.ToString();
        }

        protected void btnNum2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            counter++;
            phoneNumber[counter - 1] = 1;
            lblNumbers.Text = phoneNumber.ToString();
        }
```

My web form:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <asp:Image class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.png"/>
            <div style="text-align:center; font-size:x-large; font-weight:800">
                <asp:Label ID="lblNumbers" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </div>
      <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin:auto; width:250px; height:342px; background-image:url(Images/Telephone-keypad.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;" >
      <tbody>
      <tr>
          <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum1" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum1_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum2" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum2_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum3" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum3_Click"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum4" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum4_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum5" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum5_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum6" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum6_Click"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum7" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum7_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum8" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum8_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum9" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum9_Click"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnStar" runat="server" OnClick="btnStar_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnNum0" runat="server" OnClick="btnNum0_Click"/></td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="btnPound" runat="server" OnClick="btnPound_Click"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

When each button is clicked, I want the numbers that are clicked to display in the label as they are clicked. Currently, when I click on a button, it gives me an error page that states:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

It also includes this:

```
Source Error:


Line 21:         {
Line 22:             counter++;
Line 23:             phoneNumber[counter - 1] = 1;
Line 24:             lblNumbers.Text = phoneNumber.ToString();
Line 25:         }
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: How are you handling the post back?  You need an update panel or come to terms with the page reloading to render the content back to you.  This is forcing your array to be subtracted from zero every time, the value is not persisting.

Comment: You got answer below, but read this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetue/2010/01/14/asp-net-page-life-cycle-diagram/. You need to understand how asp works. Notice Dispose() at end. All your variables are "destroyed" after server finishes your response.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net Pages are stateless, meaning your variables like "int counter" does not maintain its value between post backs. Because of this it will always be zero, you are then subtracting 1, which results in -1 which will result in the error that you are getting. Try saving the value in a session variable, or for even better results you could use javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the value of the clicked number to the value in the label. Since you're in Webforms you can store it in ViewState instead of using a session variable (unless the user can come and go and your requirement is to preserve it).

I'd try something like this:

```
    protected void btnNum1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        appendNumber(1);
    }
.
.
.
    private void appendNumber(int number)
   {
        counter++;
        phoneNumber[counter - 1] = number;
        ViewState["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber.ToString();
   }



   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewState["phoneNumber"].ToString()))
     {
       lblNumbers.Text = ViewState["phoneNumber"].ToString()
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static int counter = 0;
```

use this ...and it will hold values between postbacks